# throw error Duplicate element Name in mongodb c# and How can i achieve nested AND/OR condition?

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4

I have mongo query which i try to retrive some data but it will display error:
"Duplicate Element Name" in MVC4.0.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();List<BsonDocument> operations = new List<BsonDocument>(); sb.Append("{\"$match\":{\"$and\": [{\"Final_Status\": \"Completed\"},{\"Final_Status\": \"Ongoing\"}],\"$and\": [{\"$or\": [{\"Final_Status\": \"Confirmed\"},{\"Final_Status\": \"Specified\"}]},{\"$or\": [{\"Final_Status\": \"Lost\"}]}]}}");
```

operations.Add(new BsonDocument(BsonSerializer.Deserialize(sb.ToString())));
var dlist = tempdatatoInsert.Aggregate(operations.ToArray());

after query execution "dlist" contains the result data.

My DB Structure

```
/* 0 */{  "_id" : ObjectId("5474456cf3e7e912ac43a898"),  "ID" : 1,  "Discovery_Month_Year" : "May-11",  "Complete_Incomplete" : "",  "Portal" : "",  "Commercial_residental" : "",  "Meeting_Not_Yet_Yes_0" : "",  "Sample_Flat" : "No",  "Project_Name" : "",  "Address" : "",  "Contact_Number" : "",  "Place" : "",  "Area" : "",  "Stop" : "",  "Builder_Group" : "Cosmos Group",  "Builder_Category" : "",  "Stage_of_Construction" : "Foundation",  "No_of_towers" : 1,  "Floor" : 30,  "Total_units" : 0,  "Tentative_completion_month_year" : "Dec-12",  "Windows_Type" : "Aluminium Sliding",  "Windows_Area" : 3000,  "Contact_Person" : "Ketan Sagar",  "Field23" : 0,  "Contact_Person_Category" : "Purchase",  "Decision_Maker" : "",  "Project_status_Specification" : "Specified After",  "Change_Product_specification" : "",  "Specified_Product" : "",  "Thickness" : ",  "Approx_tonnage" : 0,  "Pitching_Product" : "",  "Builder_Name" : "",  "Builder_contact_no" : "",  "Fabricator_Firm" : "",  "Fabricator_Name" : "",  "Fabricator_Contact" : "",  "Architect_Firm" : "",  "Architect_Name" : "",  "Architect_Contact" : "",  "Dealer_Association" : "","Next_Meeting__Follow_Up_Date" : "Feb-12",  "Next_Meeting_Follow_up_Agenda" : "",  "Remarks_about_Meeting" : "",  "Competiton_Presence" : "",  "Final_Usage_Company" : "",  "Final_Usage_Product" : "",  "Scheduled_Plan_Month_Year_1st_Lot" : "13/Apr/2013",  Scheduled_qty_in_1st_Lot" : 3000,  "Scheduled_Plan_Month_Year_2nd_Lot" : "",  Scheduled_qty_in_2nd_Lot" : "",  "Scheduled_Dealer" : "",  "Window_price_with_glass" : "",  "Price_of_Flat_Per_Sq_ft" : 0,  "Price_band_Flat" : "",  "Remarks" : "",  "Final_Status" : Prospecting",  "if_Lost_Reason" : "",  "Status" : "Cold",  "Notes" : "",  "Attachment" : ""}
```

sample Sql Query which i want to convert into MongoDB query

```
SELECT *  FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[EmpTbl] WHERE (Final_Status='Prospecting' and Final_Status='Ongoing') and (Final_Status='Completed' or Final_Status='Specified') or (Final_Status='Confirmed').
```

Comment: Can you please format the code and the JSON? It's exceptionally difficult to read as one big line.

Comment: ok here is my MongoDB query:
"{\"$match\":{\"$or\": [{\"Final_Status\": \"Completed\"},{\"Final_Status\": \"Ongoing\"},
{\"$and\": [{\"$or\": [{\"Final_Status\": \"Confirmed\"},{\"Final_Status\": \"Specified\"}]},
{\"$or\": [{\"Final_Status\": \"Lost\"}]}]}]}}"

I convert this string in BsonDocument using BsonSerializer.so how can i write the query to get proper output like above sql Query?

Answer (score 0):

You can not have multiple $and at the same level in the json document
try to rewrite your query as
    {"$match":{"$and": [{"Final_Status": "Completed"},{"Final_Status": "Ongoing"},{
    "$or":[
    {
    "Final_Status":"Confirmed"
    },
    {
    "Final_Status":"Specified"
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "$or":[
    {
    "Final_Status":"Lost"
    }
    ]
    }]}}

Comment: hey stefan then how can i write multiple $and in mongodb right now i have 3 different condition to filter the data return from mongo query. i want result which is produced by above Sql Query.so how can i achive this is there any solution for this?

Comment: you can have multiple condition inside the array that follows the $and operator, and one element inside that array can have its own $and and $or operators. Something like {$and:[{a:1},{b:2},{c:3},{$or:[{d:4},{e:5}}]}. You can also replace the $or on the same attribute with the $in operator. If you send me some sample data I can write the query for you